# I am getting an error message when I try to install react icons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, terminal, icons, npm-install

I am learning react and I am new to really using the terminal and have been trying to familiarize myself with how to use it. And I have been successful at figuring most things out from YouTube, Stack Overflow and Google without having to ask (post) a question. However I am having issues with trying to import react icons. I am going through the Youtube video teaching how to create a react todo list app. I go to the terminal in VSC on my macbook and my understanding I have npm installed. I then go to input "npm install react-icons" and at first I got a list of error messages saying

"npm warn and some description next to it. It then said at the bottom audited 2400 packages in 14s
found 77 vulnerabilities (6 low, 66 moderate, 5 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details"

I then copied and pasted "npm audit fix" After that I then got an error message very similar to the first one but this time saying if you want them to be completely updated and not have any errors then input "npm audit fix --force" Once I did this I then got this last screen shot which now I know this is very bad. And I don't know what to do next at all.

All I am trying to do is install my react icons for this project and also learn. I am very curious on the step by step process on what needs to be done to get this fixed. Thanks for your time to read this and helping out. [photo of last error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGpNQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your project setting or mac seems like has a problem.
Using terminal, my win10 laptop works exactly with command - "npm install react-icons".
Like this.

[image]

Reconstruct your project, or use "npm init -y" then, rebuild package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reaching out. I have actually gotten an update. So I input rm -rf node_modules. Which then takes me back to square one where I am now able to input the install for the react icons. I double checked to make sure they are actually accessible on my react-app package and it shows that it is listed.

Comment: Hi Malik, Appreciate your effort to look for answers in SO. Would be good if you can update your description with your findings, instead of leaving it as an answer. Also, would be good if you could format your answer correctly. You can refer this how to write good answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

214 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).